# Elias Gamma Coding and upper bound

Tags: encoding, compression

While reading about Elias Gamma coding on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elias_gamma_coding), I see it mentions that:

> "Gamma coding is used in applications where the largest encoded value is not known ahead of time."

and that:

> "It is used most commonly when coding integers whose upper-bound cannot be determined beforehand."

I don't really understand what is meant by these sentences, because whenever this algorithm is coded, the largest value of the test data or range of the test data would be known before hand. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm acquainted with Elias-gamma/delta encoding, the first sentence simply states that these compression methods are *global*, which means that it does not rely on the input data to generate the code. In other words, these methods do not need to process the input before performing the compression (as *local* methods do); it compresses the data with a function that does not depend on information from the database.

As for the second sentence, it may be taken as a *guarantee* that, although there may be some very large integers, the encoding will still perform well (and will represent such values with *feasible* amount of bytes, i.e., it is a [universal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_code_%28data_compression%29) method). Notice that, if you knew the biggest integer, some approaches (like minimal hashes) could perform better.

As a last consideration, the [same page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elias_gamma_coding) you referred to also states that:

> Gamma coding is used in applications where the largest encoded value is not known ahead of time, or to **compress data in which small values are much more frequent than large values**.

This may be obtained by generating lists of differences from the original lists of integers, and passing such differences to be compressed instead. For example, in a list of increasing numbers, you could generate:

```
list: 1 5 29 32 35 36 37
diff: 1 4 24 3  3  1  1
```

Which will give you many more small numbers, and therefore a greater level of compression, than the first list.

Comment: Thank you very much for such an elaborative response, that has really helped me!

Comment: @user1325120 You're very welcome. Please, take a minute to check my edit. I had mistaken universal/global to be synonyms, and they are **not**. Universality is related to the distribution, and guarantees that the size of each compressed number has a constant expected length (whereas non-universal methods, like the unary method, [may produce *infinitely large* representations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_code_%28data_compression%29)). It is globality that refers to using or not information from the dataset to improve the compression rate.